# Stylized hovered link moves when mouse hovers

Tags: css

I have set some links for my websites so that when the mouse hovers over the links, the text underlines. However, even though the mouse hovers, the link moves. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

NOTE: The distance between the underline and the text must be .10em, and the underline thickness must be .15em.

Heres the code:

```
.selected_works {
    color: #292929;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    right: -20px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 999;
}

.selected_works:hover {
    border-bottom: .15em solid #292929; 
    padding-bottom: .10em;
}

.selected_works:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: .15em solid #292929; 
    padding-bottom: .10em;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Without HTML markup you will not get 100% solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because of the hover style.

Here is a demo without the border + padding. See how it doesn't move.

### CSS:

```
.selected_works:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

[DEMO WITHOUT](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/FCtTm/)

And now a demo with your style:

### CSS:

```
.selected_works:hover {
    border-bottom: .15em solid #292929; 
    padding-bottom: .10em;
}
```

[DEMO WITH](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/FCtTm/1/)

With the style you are pushing the text with a border and padding. So it would move as the size is changing.

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/FCtTm/4/)

Answer (score 0):

and here we added a `<span`> so you can :hover a text-decoration:border; without moving

http://jsfiddle.net/FCtTm/2/

```
<div class="selected_works"><span>Testing</span></div>

<style type="text/css">
.selected_works:hover span {
    border-bottom: .15em solid #292929; 
    padding-bottom: .10em;
}

.selected_works:active span  {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: .15em solid #292929; 
    padding-bottom: .10em;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works 100% :)

Comment: @kenhimself glad it helped! please mark an answer as the correct one and think about upvoting answers for the effort users put in here to help